# Rendering cancel with OptiX

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a small trouble with viewport rendering in Cycles (b2.82a) + Optix [RTX 2070].

As you can see on the screenshot, it is "cancel", so objects in one of my scenes appears just gray in gray space, no matter if I created material now or it was added before. For other scenes (all of them was created in Blender 2.81 on old PC and transferred to the new PC), CUDA rendering and in Eevee+OptiX it works properly, though.

I checked ray visibility for objects and tried b2.83, where it sometimes render, sometimes cancel.

I have no idea what can cause this problem.[image: Screenshot]